# PySimpleGui - Not able to display images when the url is remote (or maybe when its jpg)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Im following along with the Image Viewer demo and have adapted the code as below

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import requests
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import io

def get_img_data(f, maxsize=(800, 640), first=False):
"""Generate image data using PIL
"""
    img = Image.open(f)
    img.thumbnail(maxsize)
    if first:                     # tkinter is inactive the first time
        bio = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(bio, format="PNG")
        del img
        print(bio.getvalue())
        return bio.getvalue()
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/JPEG_example_down.jpg'
response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
image_data = get_img_data(response.raw,first=True)
image_elem = sg.Image(data=image_data)
layout = [
        [image_elem],
         ]

window = sg.Window("Image",layout=layout)
while True:
    event,response = window.read()
    image_elem.update(data=get_img_data(response.raw, first=True))
```

I get this error

```
TclError: couldn't recognize image data
```

It doesn't matter if the get_img_data is true or false in the event loop. Both generate either this error for me or an error that says

```
'Too early to create image'
```

I think the issue might be that the url is a jpg, but the below code works fine and shows a png file.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/JPEG_example_down.jpg'
response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
img = Image.open(response.raw)
img.show()
```

Any insight into this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I copied your code and ran it and got an error of `name io is not defined`, so I added `import io`. I ran it again and got a picture of the beach scene. However, when I close the image, another error is displayed. The error is `'dict' object has no attribute 'raw'`. The error in your question isn't about this, is it?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the import io, I'll update the main post. Just to be clear, you ran this code using python3 and you were able to see the image? https://pastebin.com/k90wtJam. 
If thats true thats very strange, because Ive tried this on multiple computers.

Comment: Even when I copied the code from the referring site, I was able to confirm the seaside scenery (although the image is a bit rough).

Comment: Thats incredibly weird, can you give me more details about your system? Whats your OS and what version of python are you running?

Comment: My environment is mac os 10.13.6, python 3.6.6 PySimpleGUI 4.18.0, Pillow 6.2.1, requests 2.22.0.

Comment: Okay, thanks for taking the time in helping me. My versions are very similar to yours, so Ill try something else.

Comment: One more question, whats your tkinter version?

Comment: `$ python3 -c "import tkinter;print(tkinter.TkVersion)"` -> 8.6